# hive data load issue

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need a help in resolving a data load issue with Hive.

Background:

I have installed HDFS 1.0.3  and Hive 0.7.1  in RHEL 5.5. I am able to perform all HDFS operations. When I try to load a hive table using hive command line, I am getting the below error.

I tried loading both local file and hdfs file. Both are giving the same error. Hope I miss some configuration. Please find the attached screen shot.

I tested the script in cloudera , it works fine.

**Code:**

```
hive> describe dept;
OK
deptid  int
dname   string
Time taken: 3.792 seconds
 **-- simple hive table**
hive> ! cat /user/dept.txt;
Command failed with exit code = 1
cat: /user/dept.txt: No such file or directory
hive> ! hadoop fs -cat /user/dept.txt;
1,IT
2,Finance
3,Sales
**--  file is in hdfs**.. 
**loading file to hive table.**
hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/users/dept.txt' overwrite into table DEPT;
FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:
hdfs://informatica:8020$%7Bbuild.dir%7D/scratchdir/hive_2014-05-12_12-11-29_340_565872632113593986)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute 
URI: hdfs://informatica:8020$%7Bbuild.dir%7D/scratchdir/hive_2014-05-12_12-11-29_340_565872632113593986
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getScratchDir(Context.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getExternalScratchDir(Context.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getExternalTmpFileURI(Context.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.LoadSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(LoadSemanticAnalyzer.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:164)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error log shows that the hdfs URI is not correct, so you need to check whether there is illegal format char in your command or the hdfs URI is correct. I think the command should be as follows:
*LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/dept.txt' overwrite into table DEPT;*

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a 's' in your filename no ?

hadoop fs -cat /user/dept.txt;

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user**s**/dept.txt' overwrite into table DEPT;